# Comparison between GLfloats

Tags: c++, opengl, types

So, I am doing a little code for opengl that picks the color of one square and sum 0.01 on his value, so the color will be more shining. I have values of colors for each square in one array , and I got one variable that holds the value of the maximum one element of the color can go, in this case this value is one.
This is part of the function

```
for(GLint i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      if(colors[selectedSquare][i] > 0) {
            colors[selectedSquare][i] += 0.01;
            if(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) {
                flag = false;
            }                
      }
 }
```

I call this function in glutTimerFunc, and improve the value of the color in 0.01 for each time. When the value of the color goes egual 1 (the maxColor) i start to reducing the color in other part of the function.
The problem here is that the comparison

```
  (colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor)
```

Never gets true, I made some output to check and this is what I got

```
colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 0.99   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 0

colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 1   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 0

colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 1.01   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 0

colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 1.02   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) = 0
```

But the interesting thing starts here, when I change the comparison to

```
((int)colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor)
```

I get this output

```
colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 0.99   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 0

colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 1   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 0

colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 1.01   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 1

colors[selectedSquare][i] value = 1.02   size = 4
maxColor value = 1   size = 4
(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor) is 1
```

I measure the size using sizeof(), and the declaration of colors and maxColor is like that

```
GLfloat (Memoria::colors)[9][3] = {
{ 0.80, 0.80, 0.00 },
{ 0.00, 0.80, 0.80 },
{ 0.80, 0.00, 0.00 },
{ 0.00, 0.80, 0.00 },
{ 0.00, 1.00, 1.00 },
{ 1.00, 0.00, 0.00 },
{ 1.00, 0.00, 1.00 },
{ 1.00, 1.00, 0.00 },
{ 1.00, 1.00, 1.00 },
};

const GLfloat maxColor;
```

Both belong to the same class, but colors is static.
Hope someone knows the problem.

Comment: How is your `maxColor` defined?

Comment: Unless you really want to make your life difficult, change `if(colors[selectedSquare][i] == maxColor)` to `if(colors[selectedSquare][i] >= maxColor)`. You could do an approximate comparison, but this will be quite a bit easier.

Comment: Yes Yuushi 'maxColor' is defined in the class constructor, but now I have changed him to a '#define MAX_COLOR', but the problem still the same.

Comment: @user1905910 You've only showed a declaration, not a definition. Regardless, I agree with Jerry Coffin, using `>=` is the easiest fix to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly comparing doubles is a bad idea. You could use >=  instead of == or do something like

```
if(fabs(colors[selectedSquare][i] - maxColor) > delta)
```

where delta is a precision you want to use.

Your problem is - doubles are never stored *exactly* as you seem to expect them to be. There are always fluctuations at the end of the number far beyond the comma separated part.